# Bind to display member of combo box in item template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, devexpress

I have a combo box where I set the display member property.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit EditValue="{Binding MyEditVale}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfObjects}" DisplayMember="{Binding MyDisplayMember}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColoredTemplate}"/>
```

However, I want to use the display member property in the item template.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ColoredTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" ToolTip="This entry has been made obsolete please select another option" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsObsolete, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="{*I want to bind to the display member here*}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I am having a hard time getting this to work.
For testing purposes I have been using this code.

```
<TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
```

The object I am binding to does have a Name property but there could be other instances where this is not available.

**Is there any way to use/bind directly the display member property in the item template?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `DisplayMemberPath` or `ItemTemplate`, but not both at the same time.

**DisplayMemberPath**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfObjects}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

**ItemTemplate**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfObjects}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" ToolTip="This entry has been made obsolete please select another option" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsObsolete, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you

```
<TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DisplayMember, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEdit}}}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: I tried this and the text in the drop down list was "Name" so it did link to the display member but it brought back the string value instead of getting the value of the "Name" property on the object

Answer (score 0):

MyListOfObjects must be a collection of objects and 'Name' must be a property of the object item, then it should work. I took a code snippet from this [post](http://hintdesk.com/c-mvvmlight-toolkit-messages/) (with ListBox but it should be same for Combobox).

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFiles}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col0"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col1"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col2"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Length}" Margin="10,0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LastAccessTime}" Margin="10,0"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

SelectedFiles is just a list of FileInfo

```
public List<FileInfo> SelectedFiles
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: At the moment MyListOfObjects is a collection that has a property called Name. However, this may not always the case so I cant hard code the binding in the text box of the item template to Name. This is way I need the ability to use the display member so the binding can be set on the fly